# kendo mobile - detail disclosure indicator in list view

Tags: kendo-ui

The following snippet of kendo ui mobile creates a list with a detail disclosure indicator (a ">" icon on the right of the list cell) on the first list item, when rendering the HTML for iOS devices:

```
            <ul data-role="listview" data-click="tap_Item">
                <li id="menuItem1"><a>Item one</a></li>
                <li id="menuItem2">Item two</li>
                <li id="menuItem3">Item three</li>
            </ul>
```

Putting the "Item one" within an anchor tag gives that cell a detail disclosure indicator.

When using a custom template to generate the list:

```
<script type="text/x-kendo-template" id="custom_list">
    <h3 class="item-title">${startDate}</h3>
</script>
```

how does one give the cells a detail disclosure indicator?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The easiest thing to do would be to add the css class `km-listview-link` to the contents of the list items:

```
<li id="menuItem2"><span class="km-listview-link">Item two</span></li>
```

---

Alternatively, this is the CSS that Kendo is using to put that arrow there. You could change the selector to something else.

```
.km-listview-link:after {
    color: #7B7B7B;
    border-color: #777;
    content: "\a0";
    display: block;
    position: absolute;
    right: 1rem;
    top: 50%;
    margin-top: -0.32rem;
    margin-left: -0.2rem;
    border-style: solid;
    border-width: .24rem .24rem 0 0;
    -webkit-transform: rotate(45deg);
    -moz-transform: rotate(45deg);
    -ms-transform: rotate(45deg);
    -o-transform: rotate(45deg);
    transform: rotate(45deg);
    width: .5rem;
    height: .5rem;
    display: inline-block;
    vertical-align: middle;
}
```

Comment: Wrapping the list item's content in the "km-listview-link" span did the trick!

Answer (score 0):

I would put an anchor tag around your header and give it the listview-link role:

```
<a data-role="listview-link"><h3 class="item-title">${startDate}</h3></a>
```

Comment: The anchor shouldn't need that data-role, though stripping the whitespace around it may be necessary.

Comment: I havent tried the whitespace trick yet, but i'm currently using my own suggestion in my project and it does work.